# Unable to git-push since upgrading to SourceTree 1.6.24.0

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I keep getting the following error since upgrading to Atlassian SourceTree version 1.6.24.0 on Windows:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/********/********/'
```

Anyone else having these problems? Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/164023/password-not-working-on-sourcetree

If anyone else has the problem, just downgrade to version 1.6.23 which you can find here:

http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.6.23.exe

Comment: Thank you!  I and many of my coworkers were having this problem today.  Now we just have to downgrade and wait for a fix.